# Windows 7: Re-add feature removed with v-lite without complete reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, vlite

I made a custom Windows 7 install disk (with vLite) without Windows Media Center on it.

But now, I changed my mind and wish to install it.

Of course, Windows Media Center doesn't show up into "Turn Windows features on or off".

Anyone knows how can I install it WITHOUT REINSTALL the entire operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You've basically created your own version of "Windows 7 N", which is a version of Windows sold in Europe that does not include Media Player.

To install media player, you'll have to go to Microsoft's site for users of Windows N software.

All Media Player Downloads:

- http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/download/AllDownloads.aspx?displang=en&qstechnology=

Direct link to what you want:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=31017ed3-166a-4c75-b90c-a6cef9b414c4&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks, James. But what I actually want to instal is Windows Media CENTER ( http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-media-center/get-started/default.aspx ) Not Windows Media PLAYER.

Comment: Were you able to download Media Center off the website and resolve your issue?